# QGIS Graphical Model export Variable

Tags: qgis

I would like to export a shapefile out of the Graphical Modeler. 
When I export the data as a file, I only can give a fixed name. Is there a possibility that I can give the export a variable name? I don't want use the Python script.

Comment: Call me out if I'm wrong, but don't you specify the folder and name of the output when you run the model?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to name the output anything you choose when you run the model. Within the model itself you give the output a name but this is only for the purpose of the model.

**Please see the GIF below:**

[image]

Comment: In addition, you can also predefine a path and filename inside the model.